# Scala Playframework endpoint 404 Not Found in EC2 instance but locally works

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-ec2, playframework

I'm trying to build a web app backend which is able to process images.
Uploads image to AWS S3 and stores metadata about the image in AWS RDS instance.

The app is written in scala with the help of playframework.

The app currently has 2 endpoints.

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index()
+ nocsrf
POST    /uploadImage                controllers.StoreImageController.uploadImage()
```

The second endpoint is processing images.

The app works locally.

But when I try to run it in EC2, first endpoint is ok but for the second one I get  `404 Not Found`.

I package my app with  `dist`.

My application.conf:

```
play.http.secret.key="**************"

play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}

db {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    host = "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx:5432/hellodb"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "xxxxxx"
}

play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer = 100MB

parsers.anyContent.maxLength = 100MB
```

My Controller:

```
@Singleton
class StoreImageController @Inject() (
    controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
    imageDao: ImageDao
) extends AbstractController(controllerComponents) {

  val BUCKETNAME = "lovilovasz-images"

  def uploadImage() = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body
      .file("picture")
      .map { picture =>
        val filename = picture.filename
        val fileSize = picture.fileSize.toFloat
        val contentType = picture.contentType.getOrElse("Unknown")

        val imageMetadata = ImageMetadata(
          UUID.randomUUID(),
          filename,
          fileSize,
          contentType,
          DateTime.now().toString
        )
        imageDao.insertImageMetadata(imageMetadata)
        uploadToS3(picture)
        Ok("File uploaded")
      }
      .getOrElse {
        BadRequest("File can't be uploaded.")
      }
  }
```

So the question is:

Why does it work locally? Why do I get 404 Not found if I deploy it EC2 instance?

Actual behavior in EC2 instance:

1. First endpoint is OK.
2. Second endpoint throws 404

Expected behavior in EC2 instance:

1. First endpoint is OK.
2. Second endpoint works TOO.

Comment: How do you call the endpoint? Can you share a cURL command for instance? I'm not familiar with EC2 but if it's really a specific behaviour in EC2, it could be related to some protection rules you have to enable/disable on Amazon. Is the 404 the one from Play or does it look like an Amazon 404?

Comment: It is from Play because the default error page of Play comes up. The interesting part is that the first endpoint works.
First:
curl --request GET \
  --url http://dummy-host:9000
Second:
curl --request POST \
  --url http://dummy-host:9000/uploadImage

Comment: Wild guess: are you sure that what's deployed on EC2 is what you think?

Comment: Yes, I redeployed it twice :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send to your remote server a complex http request (all except GET without header modification) you need to handle [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem. In play it is done by adding cors filter. Note in your code you disabled csrf filter and those are different filters. Config example(application.conf in your case):

```
play.filters {
  csrf {}
  cors {
    pathPrefixes = ["/some/path", ...]
    allowedOrigins = ["http://my.frontend.com", ...]
    allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
    allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  }
}
```

More info on [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/CorsFilter#Enabling-the-CORS-filter) in play official docs.